# Div height and background-color

Tags: html, css

I have tried `overflow` and using `clear: both;` but I can't get the child div heights to be equal, I don't want the heights to be static. Can someone help me achieve this?

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkGL9/) showing the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to make .left, .middle, and .right the same height?

Comment: yes but without giving static height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have static widths, but you don't want static heights, you could fix it by setting the container `div` to `position: relative;` and then having one `div` float left, and positioning the other `div`'s absolutely. Something like in this <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkGL9/4/)</kbd>.

The one floating `div` will ensure the `container div` has a height, and the absolutely positioned `div`'s will automatically resize to the same height as the floating `div`. You would then have to set `overflow-y: auto` on the absolutely positioned `div`'s to ensure that scroll bars will appear inside of them if their height exceeds the height of the floating `div`. This should work in all browsers.

```
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px; // height will be determined by the content of div.left
}
div.left {
  float: left;
  width: 400px; // height will be determined by its content
}
div.middle, div.right {
  position: absolute;  
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;  // These two lines will ensure that this div's height
  top: 0px;     // is equal to the height of div.left and div.container
  left: 400px;  // Value should be equal to the width of div.left  
}
div.right {
  left: 600px;  // Value is the sum of the width of div.left and div.middle.
}
```

**P.S.** If all you want is for the `background-color` to fill the whole container `div` (as your post title suggests), you could just set the `background-color` on the container `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to achieve this without Javascript would be to use css3 flexible layouts

```
#newTask .body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}
```

Something like this, but prefix of the browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` on `#newtask .body` and then `display: table-cell;` on all of its child divs (left, middle, right).

This would make it behave like a table and would ensure that all divs are of equal sizes.

```
#newtask .body {
 display: table;
}

#newtask .body > div {
 display: table-cell;
 height:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mv46q/1/

Comment: This works as long as you don't need IE support.